# Splunk query to get user, saved search name, last time the query ran

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

From Splunk, I am trying to get the user, saved search name and last time a query ran ?
A single Splunk query will be nice.
I am very new to Splunk and I have tried these queries :-

```
index=_audit action=search info=granted  search=* 
| search IsNotNull(savedsearch_name)  user!="splunk-system-user"   
| table  user savedserach_name user search _time
```

The above query , is always empty for savesearch_name.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk's audit log leaves a bit to be desired.  For better results, search the internal index.

```
index=_internal savedsearch_name=* NOT user="splunk-system-user" 
| table user savedsearch_name _time
```

You won't see the search query, however.  For that, use REST.

```
| rest /services/saved/searches | fields title search
```

Combine them something like this (there may be other ways)

```
index=_internal savedsearch_name=* NOT user="splunk-system-user" 
| fields user savedsearch_name _time
| join savedsearch_name [| rest /services/saved/searches 
  | fields title search | rename title as savedsearch_name]
| table user savedsearch_name search _time
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a typo in your query.   "savedserach_name"  should be "savedsearch_name".

But I also recommend a free app that has a dedicated search tool for this purpose.
https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/6449/

Specifically the "user activity" view within that app.

Why it's a complex problem - part of the puzzle is in the audit log's info="granted" event,  another part is in the audit log's info="completed" event,   even more of it is over in the introspection index.   You need those three stitched together, and the auditlog is plagued with parsing problems and autokv compounds the problem by extracting all of fields from the SPL itself.

That User Activity view will do all of this for you,  sidestep pretty thorny autokv problems in the audit data,  and not just give you all of this per search, but also present stats and rollups by user,  app, dashboard,   even by sourcetypes-that-were-actually-searched

it also has a macro called "calculate pain" that will score a "pain" number for each search, and then sum up all the "pain" in the by-user,  by-app,  by-sourcetype rollups etc.   So that admins can try and pick off the worst offenders first.

it's up on SB here and approved for both Cloud and onprem - https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/6449/

(and there's a #sideview_ui channel for it in the community slack.)